# Opposite of Bitwise OR operation

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I compute

```
c = a 'OR' b // bitwise OR operation here
```

Now given only values of `c` and `b` how can I compute the original value of `a`?

Comment: Justto add some example- 
I have x34 and i do OR operation witn x40 and I get x74.
Now with x40 and x74, how to get x34.
for some values, i found xOR operation gives the 'a' but i am really not sure that it will always work
x34|x40=x74
x74^x40=x34

Comment: Why the negative vote? Its a perfectly clear question, and its programming relative. If its not possible even then its an answerable question.

Comment: If you do an XOR between a and b it is easy to find a if you know b and c. Just do c XOR b and you get a. With an OR it is not possible (see answers below)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is impossible.

A simple case to demonstrate my point (assuming a, b, and c are all 1-bit):

If 'b' is 1, 'c' will always be 1, you cannot determine the value of 'a'.

Comment: Yeap, and the same goes for AND.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot reliably go back.  For example, a = 0010 and b = 0011.  a OR b = 0011.  The same result is true if a was different (0001 or 0011 for example).

Answer (score 4):

Since a OR 1 is always 1 and a OR 0 is always a you can only find the value of a if b is 0.

Edit: AND and OR are lossy operations (cannot always be reversed). Whereas XOR and NOT are lossless/reversible.

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible, the or operation is not reversible. There are many different values of a that give the same value for c.

You can get one possible value of a by doing an and operation with the complement of b.

```
a = c & ~b
```

Comment: emphasis on "*possible value*"

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. There is no way to determine what 'a' will be

Answer (score 1):

from a mathematic point of view it is just not possible to deduce A from C and B.
if, for the nth bit you have the value 1 in C and in B you can't know if the nth bit in A equals 0 or 1